# How can i call create database in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code so far

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyDB]') AND type in (N'P',    N'PC'))
 DROP PROCEDURE MyDB
 GO
CREATE PROCEDURE MyDB
  @newname NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
 IF DB_ID (N'@newname') IS NULL
 CREATE DATABASE @newname
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
END
GO
```

Why is there an error on the line      CREATE DATABASE @newname. It says incorrect syntax, expecting audit_specification, db_scoped_credential ?

Comment: you should use [ ] for procedure as well  like CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyDB] GO

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250570/how-to-create-a-database-using-sql-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the syntax of [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement, I don't think you can use variable there for the database name. It needs to be a literal.

Also, most likely it needs to be in its own batch.

So, you can build a dynamic SQL statement and run it via `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`.